# Prevent DIVs from moving upon window re-size (CSS)

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm having trouble with my website here: (solved)

The problem is that when I make the window too small the content starts moving around. I'd like to make it so that it stays in one place even when the window is re-sized.

I'm using a wordpress them so something must be interfering with what I've already tried but I'm not sure.

I've tried making a wrapper around everything, and giving it a min-width, it still fails to work. I've also tried setting the position to fixed of this wrapper, the main content, and the sidebar, which also didn't work very well.

I'm kind of stumped as to what it could be. If anyone could help me out, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the media queries that are causing the problem. All of your site is trying to fit in one column if there isn't enough room for it side by side but the fixed sidebar is messing with it. Disable the media query or apply styles for the sidebar to become `display: block;` below the width set and it should be fine.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I deleted the media queries, and it worked as needed. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Starting on like 871 of the stylesheet there are media queries that change the style of the page based on the width of the browser window. You can either delete these or restyle them as you would like for tablets, phones, etc…